# C program not to allow more than n threads to execute simultaneously a function f

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, pthreads, condition-variable

Using locks/condition variables how can you make the structure of a C program  not to allow more than n threads to execute simultaneously the body of a function f?Say you have 60 created threads and only 10 are allowed to enter at once in the function. Could you write in pseudocode just as a general idea?

Comment: You're looking for [semaphores](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_wait).

Answer (score 2):

You need a mutex, a condition variable, and an integer.

1. Acquire the mutex.
2. While the integer is 10, block on the condition variable.
3. Increment the integer.
4. Release the mutex.
5. Call the function.
6. Acquire the mutex.
7. Decrement the integer.
8. Broadcast the condition variable.
9. Release the mutex.

Comment: This sounds like a very roundabout way of doing things, when semaphores exist.

Comment: @TimČas I would consider this an abuse of a semaphore. Semaphores are appropriate where one task produces something and another task consumes it. Using them as a barrier is ugly. See [this article](http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/RTOS-Mutex-Semaphore) for more.

Comment: Semaphores are used to control access to a limited number of resources (e.g. max 10 running functions). Which is what this is.

Comment: As an optimisation you can safely signal the condition variable instead of broadcasting it (every thread waiting is waiting for an identical condition, and every decrement will allow at most one more thread to make progress).

Answer (score 2):

A semaphore, as @zwol suggested, is a good fit for this job:

- You create the semaphore with its initial value being the number of threads to allow in the function at any given time.
- The first thing the function does is perform a `sem_wait()` on the semaphore.
- You ensure that on every possible code path, the function performs a `sem_post()` exactly once before returning.

Comment: @DavideVisentin, and what, exactly, is a "lock" in this context?  Not a mutex -- or at least, it's not clear that it should be a mutex.  I interpret the question to be asking about how to use synchronization objects in general, of which "locks" and condition variables are named as examples.